# Get variable used to create image

Tags: php

I'm making my own 'captcha' form and I now have a page that generates the image:

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: image/png');
   $im = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 50);

   $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
   $gray = imagecolorallocate($im, 160, 160, 160);

   imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 50, $white);

   $captcha = "SOMErandomTEXT";

   $font = 'Chewy.ttf';

   imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 0, 20, $gray, $font, $captcha);

   imagepng($im);
   imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Now I also have another page that shows this image, inside the form. Now I want to get the value `$captcha` from the page shown above on the other page. How can I do it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: @Leggendario Well, the problem is that the image-creating-page doesn't really get loaded by the browser, so there won't be the ability to create a session, right?

Comment: Why do you think it does not get loaded?

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, it does get loaded. Using sessions works even better than I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sessions did the job for me.
[PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)